# Spring data rest throws Lazy if entity is validated on beforeSave

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've an entity mapped with Spring Data Rest, and validated before save using this configuration:

```
public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", this.validator);
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", this.validator);
}
```

The entity has some LAZY collections, and unfortunately when it's validated by hibernate through Bean Validation, it throws the exception: 
" failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:"

There is a way to tell Spring to let the transaction opened, so lazy collections can be loaded?

Thanks

Below the stacktrace

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.myFleetSolutions.myFleet.fleet.domain.entity.car.Car.traceRequests, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:25) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ListValueExtractor.extractValues(ListValueExtractor.java:16) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.valueextraction.ValueExtractorHelper.extractValues(ValueExtractorHelper.java:42) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedContainerElementsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:627) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:576) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:389) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar:6.0.9.Final]
>       at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:104) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:88) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:56) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.validate(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:174) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.onBeforeSave(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener.java:114) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.AbstractRepositoryEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryEventListener.java:48) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.AbstractRepositoryEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractRepositoryEventListener.java:29) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.saveAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:447) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:397) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:848) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:245) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:245) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]

Comment: Who is `this.validator`? A custom one?

Comment: No it is org.springframework.validation.Validator

Comment: Does this question make sense to you?